# Three state checked TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I needed a CheckedTextView with three states (basicly "ignore", "include" and "exclude"), so I build my own view and it works. But I want to embed my ThreeStateTextView in a ListView, and this does not work.

The ListView recycles the views and the state gets lost. So I looked at the ListView code to see how it handles the state from CheckedTextView:

```
... setupChild(...) {
...
if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mCheckStates != null) {
    if (child instanceof Checkable) {
        ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
    }
}
....
```

So it looks like, that the ListView stores an array of booleans, which represents the states. The child is either a new created child or a recycled child.

My idea was to reimplement this method in my own listview implementation, but this method is private, so I can't do that. Here is the stacktrace, starting from BaseAdapter.getView(...):

```
xxxxxxAdapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup) line: 50    (my own BaseAdapter implementation)
ListView(AbsListView).obtainView(int, boolean[]) line: 2159 
ListView.makeAndAddView(int, int, boolean, int, boolean) line: 1831 
ListView.fillDown(int, int) line: 674   
ListView.fillFromTop(int) line: 735 
ListView.layoutChildren() line: 1652    
ListView(AbsListView).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1994  
ListView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 14003   
ListView(ViewGroup).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 4375
```

Too bad, that the important methods (obtainView and setupChild, which is called right after obtainView) are private / default access modifier.

What can I do to make my checked textview with three states work in a ListView?

// Edit:
Maybe I should rephrase my question:
You have a ListView and your own BaseAdapter implementation, but your adapter creates complex views or uses the convertView parameter (e.g. it creates a linear layout with a TextView and two Checkboxes). The problem is that the ListView does not save the states of your checkboxes.

Here is the example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How would you solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you solve that problem?

There is nothing stopping you from "holding" the state of the row in an array/list at the adapter level. For your `ThreeStateTextView` you could have an `ArrayList` of `Boolean` objects with `null`, `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` representing your three states. Then you need to set the `ThreeStateTextView` in the correct(in the `getView` method of the adapter) state by looking at the previous `ArrayList`. You'll also need to update that `ArrayList` when the state of a `ThreeStateTextView` from a row changes.

Comment: I know, but is that the way to go?

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, why not? The `ListView` saves those checked states not only for managing the state of the row but for other things like the Contextual Action Bar. Your three state `TextView` would not fit in that scenario and you'll implement it at the adapter level. If you really want to override something then you would most likely  need to extend the `AbsListView` and re-implement the entire logic of the `ListView` + your modification.

Comment: I did it now. But the problem now is: the states are not saved, when the screen rotates. I need to save the states in the fragment / activity, where I use the listview.

Comment: @PaulS. The state isn't saved you'll save it yourself and reassign it after the rotation or the other configuration change. The `ListView` does the exact thing with its checked state array, it saves that array in the `onSaveInstanceState` and restores it later when the widget is recreated.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. It just doesn't seem right. The ListView should handle that, not every (!) activity or fragment that uses a ListView with my ThreeStateTextView. The setupChild-method in ListView should be protected IMHO...

Comment: @PaulS. Making something public or protected requires a lot of thinking because you're creating a contract that you must then follow. I think the Android engineers thought about this and if they come up with the current solution, then is probably the best one. If you're worried about code duplication in your app you could always create a base `Activity`/`Fragment` to handle saving the state.

Comment: I understand your point, but I hope, that you understand my point too. My solutions works now, but it feels like a hack.